# Why linear probing only work with a relatively prime step?

Tags: c#, arrays, algorithm, data-structures

The step size is almost always 1 with linear probing, but it is acceptable to use other step sizes as long as the step size is relatively prime to the table size so that every index is eventually visited. If this restriction isn't met, all of the indices may not be visited...
(The basic problem is: You need to visit every index in an array starting at an arbitrary index and skipping ahead a fixed number of indices [the skip] to the next index, wrapping to the beginning of the array if necessary with modulo.)

I don't understand why not all indices could be visited if the step size isn't relatively prime to the table size,and I don't understand why the converse is true: that all the indices will be visited if the step size is relatively prime to the array size.

I've observed this relatively prime property working in several examples that I've worked out by hand, but I don't understand why it works in every case.

In short, my question is: Why is every index of an array visited with a step that is relatively prime to the array size? Is there a proof of this?

Answer (score 1):

Say you have 10 elements and using a step of 2 starting at 0. You will visit 0, 2, 4, 6, 8 then wrap around and start over. You would miss all the odd numbers.

Answer (score 0):

First, if the step size s is not relatively prime to the table size t, then there is some common factor d greater than 1. You only hit indices that are multiples of d by taking steps of size s followed by reducing the index mod t.

Second, if s and t are relatively prime, then there is some pair of integers a and b so that as + bt = 1. This can be proved using [Euclid's algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_algorithm), or by showing that the greatest common divisor of s and t is the smallest positive number of the form as + bt. The value a (which can be constructed from Euclid's algorithm, as described on the linked page) is the multiplicative inverse of s mod t. This means that after a steps, you are at position 1. For any other position p, you will reach position p after a*p steps, if not sooner.

For example, 7 is relatively prime to 100. 7*43 + 100*(-24) = 1. So, the multiplicative inverse of 7 mod 100 is 43. Suppose we want to know a time when you reach position 20 by taking steps of size 7. One of those times is after 20*43 = 860 steps. You also reach position 20 after 60, 160, 260, etc. steps, which you can verify since 7*60 = 420, and 420 mod 100 is 20.